# How to deploy a project on GitHub Pages from dist folder

Tags: github, deployment, github-pages

I have built my project with parcel and it gave me all my files in dist folder and I push it to a repo on GitHub. now I have dist folder and also src folder ( which was for develop phase). How can I deploy the page from dist folder using git ( on Github site I only know how to deploy from main branch not from another folder).
here is the repo address:
[click to go to repo](https://github.com/alisafa1371/forkifyApp-v1)

Comment: Where you want to deploy your page? On github pages?

Comment: yes on github pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your dist folder as `docs` on your local repository, git add, commit and push. After that open your repo, go to Settings > Pages, leave the source dropdown on "Deploy from a branch", on branch dropdown select your `main` branch and select the docs folder, and you are ready to go.

[image]